# Do disillusionment charms only affect sight, or other senses, too?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I brought up disillusionment charms before, which lead to some interesting answers and another thought has occurred to me that is related to my [previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9498/do-disillusionment-charms-fail-at-very-close-range).

Do disillusionment charms work only on sight, or on the other senses?  Hogwarts (and this is the example I used in the other question, but never got an answer that applied to this) is protected with disillusionment charms.  If a building is made, through such a charm, to look like ruins, will it feel that way too?

Here's an example: Say you have a stone building you want to hide from muggles, so you cast a disillusionment charm on it so it looks like ruins.  From the muggle's point of view, a stone wall has fallen down, but in reality, that wall is there.  If he waves his hand in what he sees as empty space where the wall was, will his hand hit the wall, or will the spell make him feel just air there?

Or will something else happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the other senses, all the descriptions explicitly say "invisible" or "can't see," and never mention other senses. They certainly don't hide the user aurally, the trio had to cast muffliato on their tent in addition to disillusionment, and they could be heard under Harry's cloak, which was superior to disillusionment-based cloaks.

Regarding Hogwarts, it is *not* protected by disillusionment charms, it's the muggle-repelling charms that make it look like ruins. Disillusionment charms don't make a building look like something else, they make it look like nothing.  And disillusionment charms work the same on wizards as on muggles.   If you wave your hand behind a disillusioned object, you should see it as if the object weren't there (as long as the spell was cast by a sufficiently powerful wizard).  The charms don't vanish the object entirely, though, so if you walked into something disillusioned, you would feel it (and that's another sense they don't impair).  If you cast some *illusionment* charm on a building to make it look like a wall had crumbled, you would probably still see your hand behind it, and since you're not actually altering the building itself (in particular the fact that it's there), you should still touch the wall even if you can't see it.